# Joining Values with a common key in specific place

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

i try to find a way to join values that share a common key (in the below example it would be the ID) into a specified place in a dataframe.

Where i start:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"ID" : ["x13", "x13", "", "x14", "" , "x13"], "Name":"Master1", "Slave1", "Master2", "Master3", "Master4" , "Slave2"],"value":["", "5", "7", "8", "", "1"]})
```

Output is as expected:

```
ID     Name      value
0  x13  Master1
1  x13   Slave1     5
2       Master2     7
3  x14  Master3     8
4       Master4
5  x13   Slave2     1
```

What i want to achieve is the following result:

```
ID     Name      value
0  x13  Master1     5,1
1  x13   Slave1     5
2       Master2     7
3  x14  Master3     8
4       Master4
5  x13   Slave2     1
```

In words: I want to loop through the datarame and find all not empty ID's. When found i want to join up all the values which have the common ID in a list, and store that back in the datframe on the Master of this specific ID.

All my solution attemps ended up in loop in loop ...

I am kind of sure that the solution would be related to the groupby functionality of pandas but I cannot get the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use `groupby` and then map a series via a mask:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID" : ["x13", "x13", "", "x14", "" , "x13"],
                   "Name": ["Master1", "Slave1", "Master2", "Master3", "Master4" , "Slave2"],
                   "value":["", "5", "7", "8", "", "1"]})

s = df[(df.ID != '') & (df.value != '')].groupby('ID')['value'].apply(list)

mask = df['ID'].isin(s.index) & df['Name'].str.startswith('Master')
df.loc[mask, 'value'] = df.loc[mask, 'ID'].map(s).apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x))

print(df)

#     ID     Name value
# 0  x13  Master1  5, 1
# 1  x13   Slave1     5
# 2       Master2     7
# 3  x14  Master3     8
# 4       Master4      
# 5  x13   Slave2     1
```